# Boto AWS CloudSearch return rank / score

Tags: boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Boto's CloudSearch API to query a CloudSearch index. I cannot see a way to retrieve the rank / score of each search result. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add the name of the rank expression to the return_fields argument:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch(key,secret)
domain = conn.create_domain('domain_name')
search_service = domain.get_search_service()

results = search_service.search(query, return_fields=['text_relevance','name_of_custom_rank_expression'])

for result in results:
    score = result['data']['name_of_custom_rank_expression'][0]
```